# How do I multiple all integers in a list? --Python

Tags: python, multiplication

```
list1= [1,2,3,4]
```

1) I want to multiply every element in this list in order to output 24. How do I do this in python without using a for loop? Are there in-built libraries to do this?

2) And what if `list1` contains string such as

```
list1= ["1,2,3,4"]
```

3) And what if `list1` contains string such as

```
list1 = ['1234']
```

Comment: oh! come on. Stop adding these new sub-problems.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use:

```
import operator
reduce(operator.mul, [1,2,3,4])
```

*out:*

```
24
```

As for the performance, using `operator.mul` is somewhat faster:

```
In [1]: from operator import mul

In [2]: lst = [1,2,3,4]

In [3]: reduce(mul,lst)
Out[3]: 24

In [4]: %timeit reduce(mul,lst)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 733 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,lst)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 us per loop
```

If you have the numbers as a string:

```
In [6]: reduce(mul,map(int,["1,2,3,4"][0].split(',')))
Out[6]: 24
```

For large lists you can also use `itertools.imap` that returns an iterator:

```
In [7]: from itertools import imap

In [8]: %timeit reduce(mul,imap(int,["1,2,3,4"][0].split(',')*10000))
1 loops, best of 3: 264 ms per loop
```

*EDIT:*
and hopefully with your last edit:

```
In [18]: reduce(mul,map(int,['1234'][0]))
Out[18]: 24
```

Comment: You should use `imap` instead of `map` in the last part, as you are going to process the result with an iterative function. For bigger lists this should be much faster.

Comment: You should also include the `import` step in your timeits. But for large lists, ultimately `mul` wins.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- it depends much of the context: are you going to use it once or multiple times in your code -- going to be biased every way :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce()`, or `functools.reduce()` in py3x:

```
In [4]: list1= [1,2,3,4]

In [5]: reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,list1)
Out[5]: 24
```

In python 3.3 you can also use [`itertools.accumulate()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import islice,accumulate
list1= [1,2,3,4]
le=len(list1)
it=accumulate(list1,operator.mul)
print list(islice(it,le-1,le))[-1]    #prints 24
```

Edit:
In case of string, you've to split the string first using `str.split(",")` and then apply `int()`to the list returned:

```
In [6]: list1= ["1,2,3,4"]

In [7]: reduce(operator.mul,map(int,list1[0].split(",")))
Out[7]: 24
```

Comment: Note that you have to get `reduce` from `functools` in Python 3

Comment: I would prefer `operator.mul` instead of a lambda expression.

Comment: @schlamar ah! missed that, btw root already used that in his answer.

Comment: What if the list1 is a string, such as list1= ["1,2,3,4"]?

Comment: I would use a list comprehension instead of the map for parsing though, more pythonic.

Comment: You should note that `itertools.accumulate` returns an iterator over all the intermediate results. So it's not exactly the same.

Comment: @root yeah I forgot to add, **"with slight modifications"**.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an implementation of multiply w/o loops (using recursion and tail recursion).

```
 " A recursive implementation"        
def mul_recursive(nos):
    if len(nos) == 1:
        return nos[0]
    return nos[0] * mul_recursive(nos[1:])


" A tail recursive implementation"
def mul_tailrecursive(nos):
    def multiply(nos,mul_so_far):
        if len(nos) == 1:
            return nos[0]*mul_so_far
        return multiply(nos[1:],mul_so_far * nos[0])
    return multiply(nos,1)

print mul_recursive([1,2,3,4,5])
print mul_tailrecursive([2,3,4])
```

Comment: This will fail for something like `range(1000)` or above, python has recursion limit.

Comment: ya..you are right..but this is bad..any chance we can make recursion work for larger lists?

Comment: you can use `sys.setrecursionlimit()` to increase the limit, but not a good idea per se.